# Tensorflow: parallelize tensor that runs a dequeue

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using Tensorflow to run some processing code over images. I have

- a FIFOQueue called `some_queue`
- a tensor called `t` that is built by `some_op(some_other_op(some_queue.dequeue()))`, so that each run dequeues one element from `some_queue` and performs operations on it.

All the elements in the queue can be processed in parallel, so I'd like to run `t` several times but in parallel (ie not call `session.run(t)` in a loop).

I've tried things like `session.run([t] * size_of_queue)` and `session.run(tf.tuple(*([t] * size_of_queue))` but neither work properly. What's the proper way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Excellent question!

Comment: You can do `dequeue_many`. That'll give you a tensor of values, and you then use slicing to split it into separate examples